# Unable to pass an object to an AngularUI modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've recently started my studies of AngularJS, and am researching the uses of the [Angular UI for Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) framework.

However, I've hit a snag in a really basic test case!

[Fiddle: My Failing Modal](http://jsfiddle.net/pEmXt/)

What I'm trying to do, is open a modal with a dynamic title and content (in this simple test, I'm merely sourcing that from the `$scope.open(_, _, _)` call, for simplicity).

However, one small problem - following the [Modal Example on the Angular UI for Bootstrap page](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), I find myself unable to pass a `params` object from the `ModalController` (the controller for the section that is handling the modal demo),  to the `ModalInstanceController`, which controls individual modal dialogues.

Specifically, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
at new <anonymous> (http://fiddle.jshell.net/pEmXt/show/:68:24)
at invoke (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:3624:28)
at Object.instantiate (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:3636:23)
at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:6639:28
at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js:8:28715
at wrappedCallback (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:10597:81)
at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:10683:26
at Scope.$eval (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:11576:28)
at Scope.$digest (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:11421:31)
at Scope.$apply (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:11682:24)
```

**Question**: How do I properly pass arguments from the overarching controller, to the dialogue instance controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed a little bit the code in your fiddle.

In particular, added:

```
$scope.params = [];
```

and

```
resolve: {
    params: function() {
        $scope.params = {
            title: modalTitle,
            message: modalMessage
        }
        return $scope.params;
    }
}
```

inside `ModalController`. I also changed how you declare the controllers:

```
var ModalController = function ($scope, $modal, $log) { ...

var ModalInstanceController = function ($scope, $modalInstance, params) { ...
```

based on the example you linked.

http://jsfiddle.net/pEmXt/2/

Comment: Thanks!  It works!

...But to the learning part.  Why can't I use `[controllerObject].controller(usualAngularStuff)` to define my controller?  Why do I have to use a function object as the controller instead?

Comment: What do you mean by [controllerObject] ?

Comment: In my original example, I define an `angular.module` for the app's controller's, and then use the `controller` method to define a controller on that module.  Why do controllers defined on modules fail to work with the Angular UI for Bootstrap Modal, but raw functions work just fine?

Comment: You can. I read again your code and there were a few semantic errors (e.g. sometimes you wrote both `demoApp` and `app`). Here's the fixed code with angular controllers' definition http://jsfiddle.net/pEmXt/5/